# baguetteBox - lightbox not working inside knockout js foreach binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, knockout.js, baguettebox

I try to preview image using `baguetteBox.run` when clicking an image.
The problems are, whenever I click image src inside `foreach` binding. It redirect to new File src page `(File: C/(file url)` instead of loading a lightbox pop-up.
Here my view:

```
<section class="gallery-block cards-gallery">
    <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: PatrolGalleryList">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
             <div class="card border-0 transform-on-hover">
                  <a class="lightbox" data-bind="attr:{href: ImgUrl}">
                  <img data-bind="attr:{src: ImgUrl}" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top">
                  </a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But if I try creating an img div outside `foreach` binding and click on the image. The lightbox popup preview the image successfully. E.g:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
         <div class="card border-0 transform-on-hover">
              <a class="lightbox" data-bind="attr:{src: SingleImgUrl}">
              <img data-bind="attr:{src: SingleImgUrl}" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top">
              </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here the js:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/baguetteBox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            baguetteBox.run('.cards-gallery', { animation: 'slideIn' });
     });
```

Comment: Just a guess... baguettebox does not work with file-protocoll, does it work withut knockout using the same src´s ?

Comment: Yes. If I don't use knockout binding. Just pure hard code src's file url. baguettebox run perfectly.

Comment: In your foreach, maybe try to access the currently iterated item with $data eg.: `<img data-bind="attr:{src: $data.ImgUrl}"` i´m guessing that ImgUrl is not a valid property or function of the iterated item